# How to use event.stopPropagation() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, stoppropagation

I have three elements with events assigned to them. How should I use `event.stopPropagation` so only events for elements #1 and #2 are executed, but not for #3? I put `event.stopPropagation` in element #2 as it stops bubbling. In my understanding, it should stop the triggering of the event in #3 but it doesn't seem to be working, all events are still being executed. Here is JS code:

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      document.querySelector('#element1').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log('Event in #element1 fired!');
      });

      document.querySelector('#element2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Event in #element2 fired!');
      });

      document.querySelector('#element3').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log('Event in #element3 fired!');
      });
    });
```

```html
<div id="element3" class="element">
  Element 3
  <div id="element2" class="element">
    Element 2
    <div id="element1" class="element">
      Element 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/u2hL5sh9/, it doesn't completely stop events for element 3, it just stops the event from bubbling up when clicking the other two ?

Comment: You should be using `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: ^ that's true, the posted code won't work in Firefox.

Comment: But how to stop event in element #3? I don't want it to be triggered at all. Is it possible?

Comment: Not unless you remove the event handler *(or the element)*

Comment: You don't say on which element you are clicking, or what should happen for each one.

Comment: When I click on #1 or #2 I want their events to be executed, but not events for #3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

because the parameter with the event object passed to the function is named `e`.

You need to write this as:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```